# Can you use the momentjs object constructor when specifying the weekYear?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get the date of the Monday of the first week of this year, working in utc.

If I create a moment like this:

```
moment.utc().week(1).weekYear(2014).toDate() //Date {Mon Dec 30 2013 09:28:42 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)}
```

Everything is fine. The problem is I prefer the look and readability of the object constructor like this:

```
 moment.utc({week: 1, weekYear:2014 }).toDate() //  Date {Sun Jan 19 2014 11:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)}
```

Which does not yield the same result, I assume that the second option is broken and just returning the first day of the current week.

Is there no weekYear object for this constructor, or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like for the moment you can't do it. Its a shame, but this way isn't too bad, although not as readable. This code will set the moment to the first week of the pasted in year (ISO week and ISO year)

```
moment.utc('01-' + myYear(), 'WW-GGGG')
```